# Pass UIimage drawing to another viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Im new to the iOS development and searched before posting, but couldn't figure out how to make the image passing work at all in my project. I need to pass the UIimage that the user drew from DrawViewController to the the Draw2viewController.`#import

```
//DrawViewController.h
@interface DrawViewController : UIViewController {

CGPoint lastPoint;
CGFloat red;
CGFloat green;
CGFloat blue;
CGFloat brush;
CGFloat opacity;
BOOL mouseSwiped;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *tempDrawImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *mainImage;
- (IBAction)pencilPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)eraserPressed:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Sentence1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Done;



@end`
```

------------------DrawViewController.m------------------

```
#import "DrawViewController.h"
#import "Draw2ViewController.h"
#import "SentenceViewController.h"

@interface DrawViewController ()

@end

@implementation DrawViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    red = 0.0/255.0;
    green = 0.0/255.0;
    blue = 0.0/255.0;
    brush = 10.0;
    opacity = 1.0;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    Draw2ViewController *view2 = [[Draw2ViewController alloc] init];
    view2.myImage = _mainImage;

    _Sentence1.text = _SentStr;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)pencilPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton * PressedButton = (UIButton*)sender;

    switch(PressedButton.tag)
    {
        case 0:
            red = 0.0/255.0;
            green = 0.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 1:
            red = 105.0/255.0;
            green = 105.0/255.0;
            blue = 105.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 2:
            red = 255.0/255.0;
            green = 0.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 3:
            red = 0.0/255.0;
            green = 0.0/255.0;
            blue = 255.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 4:
            red = 102.0/255.0;
            green = 204.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 5:
            red = 102.0/255.0;
            green = 255.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 6:
            red = 51.0/255.0;
            green = 204.0/255.0;
            blue = 255.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 7:
            red = 160.0/255.0;
            green = 82.0/255.0;
            blue = 45.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 8:
            red = 255.0/255.0;
            green = 102.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 9:
            red = 255.0/255.0;
            green = 255.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
    }



}

- (IBAction)eraserPressed:(id)sender {

    red = 255.0/255.0;
    green = 255.0/255.0;
    blue = 255.0/255.0;
    opacity = 1.0;
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
    self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ImagePass"])
    {
        Draw2ViewController *D2V = [segue destinationViewController].
       D2V.myImage = _mainImage;
    }
}
@end
```

And Draw2viewController has just been created so there is only the default code in it

Comment: Do you use storyboard to switch from DrawViewController to Draw2viewController view or you create Draw2viewController and present it prog?

Comment: yes, storyboard is used so couldn't i call the parent view controller.                 (UIImage *) self.parentViewController.mainImage i think…..

Comment: See prepareForSegue option in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your Draw2viewController.h file add:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *myImage;
```

And in your DrawViewController import `Draw2viewController.h` and  when you present your view programatically you can do:

```
Draw2viewController *view2 = [[Draw2viewController alloc] init];
view2.myImage = YOUR_UIIMAGE_YOU_WANT_PASS;
// Code for presenting/pushing view2 to view hierarchy
```

Or when you do it via storyboard with segue do it in prepareForSegue: method:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOURIDENTIFIER"])
        {
            Draw2viewController *view2 = (Draw2viewController*)[segue destinationViewController].
            view2.myImage = YOUR_UIIMAGE_YOU_WANT_PASS;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the prepare for segue in the drawViewController.m or will i have to add the code manually?

Comment: You have to add it to drawViewController.m. Note that I added [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOURIDENTIFIER"] to the answer. Remember to add identifier name to your segue in storyboard and replace YOURIDENTIFIER to your one.

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:    (id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ImagePass"])
        {
            Draw2ViewController *view2 = (Draw2viewController*)     [segue destinationViewController].
            view2.myImage = _mainImage;
        }
    }                                                                   Gives an error "Property view2 not found on object of type id????

Comment: neither way worked, I got the error above from trying the segue and when i tried to push the image it would run but no image was passed

Comment: Can you transition to Draw2ViewController?

Comment: yes if i do the push image method, but not if i use PrepareForSegue. but now image is shown for the transition

Comment: Did you specify view controller classes in respective xib in storyboards?

Comment: yes The controller classes are paired with the storyBoard correctly

Comment: I edited the code above so it shows the segue issue. My error is "Property 'D2V' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: How many segue have you got from your DrawViewController? What do you mean by use PrepareForSegue? Do you try to call it manually? Which line gives you that error? That line Draw2ViewController *D2V = [segue destinationViewController]. ends with dot but it should be ;

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a delegate protocol. The reference for delegates can be found at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html).

Or, you could use NSNotificationCenter with an NSNotification's userInfo containing the image. NSNotification's documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Please explain the down-vote so I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: We used delegate when you need callback implementation mostly, for instance if you have NSOperation where you are performing some length operation, you used delegate implementation to notify NSOperations's delegate of its outcome once it is complete. In the above statement, you won't need a delegate as it is pretty straightforward, you are transition from one view controller to other where you can pass any values to other view controller in prepareForSegue by getting reference of segue's destination view controller and setting its respective properties.